# UI tests for a wpf application are getting failed while running with WinAppDriver

Tags: appium-desktop, winappdriver

I got a couple of tests created using `Selenium.Appium.Windows` for a `WPF` (windows presentation application). I am using `WinAppDriver` to run the test but unfortunately some of the UI test are getting failed with the below error; Any pointers will be much appreciated.

**Message:**

> System.InvalidOperationException : An element could not be located on
>   the page using the given search parameters.

```
Result StackTrace:  
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1.FindElement(String by, String value)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1.FindElementByAccessibilityId(String selector)
```

Started the server `WinAppDriver` server and its running

Following are my environment details:

```
WinAppDriver 1.1 version
Window 10 Pro, 32 GB RAM, i7-7500U Processor
NET Core 3.0 SDK
```

Answer (score 1):

There's only so much we can do to troubleshoot by only looking at an error message. In general when asking for help on this site it's a good idea to include a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that will reproduce the problem.

Your application is failing to find any element that has the automation ID you are searching for. The best thing to do to diagnose a failure to find an automation ID is to inspect the element you were hoping to select using a tool like [inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) and see what the actual value of its AutomationId is.

You may also want to check to see that you're hooking into the correct application. Even if the ID exists if you're looking in the wrong place you're not going to find it.

It can also be helpful to run a debugger step by step through your test to see whether there is a more complex reason for failure, like elements not being fully loaded when you search for it.

Comment: On click on that menu item, in that inspect window the automation id is displaying  ""

Comment: Then that element doesn't have an automation ID set. You'll have to locate the element using other locators, like class, name, ID, or XPath.

Comment: It has an automation id but, it toggle appears and disappers while moving the cursor over the menu each time

Comment: Perhaps you should ask another question specifically about the issue you are having with automation IDs changing upon mouse over and how to identify those elements using winappdriver. Be sure to provide a MVCE so that it's easy for other people to be able to help out.

Comment: @sphennings Please consider splitting up your answer. Your answer addresses 3 different things. I could be wrong, but I consider it good practice to ask for more information or help debugging in a comment and reserve a answer for effectively answering a question.

Comment: @PixelPlex I thought about splitting my answer, or trying to encourage the OP to refine their answer through comments. I decided there was value in an answer that empowers the OP to troubleshoot the issue on their own. Think of my answer as less "Here are 3 solutions to your problem. One of which may work for your particular case." and more "This is how you troubleshoot element_not_found errors when using WinAppDriver."